# Nokogiri XML.children returning formatting elements in addition to actual elements. How does one avoid this?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<attributes>
    <intelligence>27</intelligence>
    <memory>21</memory>
    <charisma>17</charisma>
    <perception>17</perception>
    <willpower>17</willpower>
</attributes>
```

I want to parse the following:

```
intelligence: 27, memory: 21, charisma: 17, perception: 17, willpower: 17
```

When I try this code:

```
def get_attributes(api)
  attributes = []
  api.xpath("//attributes").children.each do |attribute|
    name = attribute.name.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')
    text = attribute.text
    attributes << "#{name}: #{text}"
  end
  attributes
end
```

I get results with newline data (because of the formatting) for every even-numbered child:

```
#(Text "\n      ")
#(Element:0x3ffe166fdb9c { name = "intelligence", children = [ #(Text "20")] })
#(Text "\n      ")
#(Element:0x3ffe166f71ac { name = "memory", children = [ #(Text "25")] })
#(Text "\n      ")
#(Element:0x3ffe166f3818 { name = "charisma", children = [ #(Text "23")] })
#(Text "\n      ")
#(Element:0x3ffe166f0604 { name = "perception", children = [ #(Text "16")] })
#(Text "\n      ")
#(Element:0x3ffe166b52e8 { name = "willpower", children = [ #(Text "15")] })
#(Text "\n    ")
```

Is there a method in Nokogiri that will skip these 'formatting-only' children?  Or do I have to manually traverse only the odd numbered elements?

I expect `api.xpath("//attributes").children` to navigate the actual children, not the formatting text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`children`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-children) method will return all child nodes of the target node, including text nodes. If you just want all element node children, you can specify it in your XPath query using `*`:

```
def attributes(api)
  api.xpath('//attributes/*').each_with_object([]) do |n, ary|
    ary << "#{n.name}: #{n.text}"
  end
end
```

This will return an array of strings with the format `name: value`, which is what it looks like you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is "no".  However, you can easily do:

```
if attribute.element?
    name = attribute.name.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')
    text = attribute.text
    attributes << "#{name}: #{text}"
end
```

to get the desired effect.  Alternatively, this version may be slightly more readable:

```
if ! attribute.text?
   name = ...
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the text nodes for the children, use:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<attributes>
    <intelligence>27</intelligence>
    <memory>21</memory>
    <charisma>17</charisma>
    <perception>17</perception>
    <willpower>17</willpower>
</attributes>
EOT

doc.at('attributes').children.map(&:text)
```

Which returns:

```
["27", "21", "17", "17", "17"]
```

From there you can easily do:

```
'intelligence: %02d, memory: %02d, charisma: %02d, perception: %02d, willpower: %02d' % doc.at('attributes').children.map(&:text)
=> "intelligence: 27, memory: 21, charisma: 17, perception: 17, willpower: 17"
```

If you want it to be a bit more structured, you can do:

```
doc.at('attributes').children.each_with_object({}){ |o,h| h[o.name] = o.text }
=> {"intelligence"=>"27", "memory"=>"21", "charisma"=>"17", "perception"=>"17", "willpower"=>"17"}
```

Or:

```
doc.at('attributes').children.each_with_object({}){ |o,h| h[o.name.to_sym] = o.text }
=> {:intelligence=>"27", :memory=>"21", :charisma=>"17", :perception=>"17", :willpower=>"17"}
```

---

```
doc.at('attributes').children
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3245fb8fc name="intelligence" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3245fb6f4 "27">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3245fb4ec name="memory" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3245fb2e4 "21">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3245fb0dc name="charisma" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3245faed4 "17">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3245fecb4 name="perception" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3245feaac "17">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3245fe8a4 name="willpower" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3245fe69c "17">]>]
```

Comment: Using your first one-liner I still get a carriage return character element (but it is quite close): `{:text=>"\n    ", :intelligence=>"20", :memory=>"25", :charisma=>"23", :perception=>"16", :willpower=>"15"}`

Comment: If you are getting carriage returns then there is something wrong/missing. You can see that the code above doesn't do anything special and the CR isn't there. The text nodes exist outside the children, but they're not being returned.

Comment: Nokogiri is currently at v1.5.6. If you're not on the most recent version you might try updating it using `gem update nokogiri`.

Comment: I am using the most recent version - there just appears to be an element within my actual XML that is counted as a child with an object `text=>"\n "`  I assume it has something to do with my source - although it'd be nice to know how to avoid it in this case.